# Using Doctrine in Joomla 1.5

Tags: doctrine, joomla1.5

I'm trying to use Doctrine in Joomla 1.5 but have not been able to get anything running.

According to this article: http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-may-2011/item/447-using-doctrine-ORM-in-joomla

I immediately get `Fatal error: Class 'Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in /var/www/html/hosts/joomla/public_html/components/com_bugs/bugs.php on line 13`

The bugs.php looks like this:

```
// no direct access 
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // Include dependancies 
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
//require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/bootstrap.php');
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper.php');
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');
//$controller = new BugsController(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller = JController::getInstance('Bugs');
```

Not sure how to implement this, when trying to use the $controller = new BugsController the error is: `Fatal error: Class 'JController' not found in`

This because I have the autoload on in bugs.php and have /public_html/components/com_bugs/controller.php extend /public_html/libraries/doctrine/JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper.php the JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper exends JController but JController cannot be found anymore after composer and the autoload did something.

I'm starting to think that it's not possible to use Joomla with Doctrine since Doctrine has to be installed with composer (didn't find any other documentation on how to download and configure it) and composer seems to want everything in vendor so have to put all the Joomla classes in vendor too?

**[UPDATE]**

It looks like whatever composer does in /public_html/libraries/doctrine/vendor/autoload.php completely breaks `jimport('joomla.application.component.controller')`

Not including the autoload however gives me another problem, like none of the Doctrine classes are found: `Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found`

Maybe I'll try and hack /public_html/libraries/doctrine/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php to try and see if that one can load Joomla classes for me.

Comment: Not sure and I don't know joomla, but doesn't the article state that you'll need joomla 1.6 and not 1.5? Also, are you sure the article is related to Doctrine2 and not Doctrine1?

Answer (score 1):

Either jimport or composer won't work because jimport defines `__autoload`. Instead of `__autoload` I'm using `spl_autoload_register` that only seems to work with PHP version starting from 5.1.2.

Changed loader:
/public_html/libraries/loader.php

```
class JLoader
{
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        if(JLoader::load($class)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
//... other code and comments
    function import( $filePath, $base = null, $key = 'libraries.' )
    {
        static $paths;
        if (!isset($paths)) {
              $paths = array();
              //assuming PHP 5 >= 5.1.2
              spl_autoload_register(array('JLoader', 'autoload'), true, true);
        }
//remove the __autoload function
```

The bugs.php looks like this:

/public_html/components/com_bugs/bugs.php

```
<?php
// no direct access 
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // Include dependancies 
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/bootstrap.php');
require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/doctrine/JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper.php');
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');


//using links like /index.php?option=com_bugs&format=text&task=save
// defaults to link so above is same as: http://joomla/index.php?option=com_bugs&format=text&task=save&router=link
$route=JRequest::getVar('router', 'Link');
$controllerName = 'bugsController'.$route;
//include the controller
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/controllers/'.$route.".php");
$controller = new bugsControllerlink(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->setEntityManager(bootstrapDoctrine());
$controller->execute(JRequest::getVar('task', ''));
$controller->redirect();

/**
 * Initialize doctrine by setting the entities and proxies locaties. Also define 
 * a default namespace for the proxies. 
 */
function bootstrapDoctrine() {
  $doctrineProxy = new JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper(JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper::APP_MODE_DEVELOPMENT);
  $doctrineProxy->setEntityLibrary(dirname(__FILE__) . '/models');
  $doctrineProxy->setProxyLibrary(dirname(__FILE__) . '/proxies');
  $doctrineProxy->setProxyNamespace('Joomla\Proxies');
  $doctrineProxy->setConnectionOptions(getConfigurationOptions());
  $doctrineProxy->bootstrap();
  return $doctrineProxy->getEntityManager();
}

function getConfigurationOptions() { // Define database configuration options 
  $joomlaConfig = JFactory::getConfig();
  return array('driver' => 'pdo_mysql', 'path' => 'database.mysql'
          , 'dbname' => $joomlaConfig->getValue("config.data.db")
          , 'user' => $joomlaConfig->getValue("config.data.user")
          , 'password' => $joomlaConfig->getValue("config.data.password"));
}   
?>
```

The link controller looks like: (file name has start with a capital L)
/public_html/components/com_bugs/controllers/Link.php

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
// import Joomla controller library (done by composer)
//jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
class bugsControllerlink extends JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper{
     function __construct()
           {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->registerTask( 'show','show' );
              $this->registerTask( 'save','save' );
           }
    function save(){
        $model=$this->getModel('link');
        $view = $this->getView('show','text');
        $view->setLayout('save');
        $model->em=$this->getEntityManager();
        $view->data = $model->save();
        $view->display();
    }
}
```

Didn't change the boodtrap, that still looks like this:
/public_html/libraries/doctrine/bootstrap.php

```
<?php
 interface JoomlaDoctrineController { 
     public function setEntityManager(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager);
 }
?>
```

The /public_html/libraries/doctrine/JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper.php looks like:

```
<?php

/** * Configuration class to integrate Doctrine into Joomla. * 
 * @author pderaaij <removed email, check link in question> */
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration,
    Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
jimport( 'joomla.application.component.controller' );    
class JoomlaDoctrineBootstrapper extends JController{
  const APP_MODE_DEVELOPMENT = 1;
  const APP_MODE_PRODUCTION = 2;

  private $applicationMode;
  private $cache;
  private $entityLibrary;
  private $proxyLibrary;
  private $proxyNamespace;
  private $entityManager;
  private $connectionOptions;

  public function __construct($applicationMode=1) {
    $this->applicationMode = $applicationMode;
    $this->_name="bugs";
    parent::__construct();
  }
  public function getConnectionOptions() {
    return $this->connectionOptions;
  }
  public function setConnectionOptions($connectionOptions) {
    $this->connectionOptions = $connectionOptions;
  }
  public function getProxyLibrary() {
    return $this->proxyLibrary;
  }
  public function setProxyLibrary($proxyLibrary) {
    $this->proxyLibrary = $proxyLibrary;
  }
  public function getProxyNamespace() {
    return $this->proxyNamespace;
  }
  public function setProxyNamespace($proxyNamespace) {
    $this->proxyNamespace = $proxyNamespace;
  }
  public function getCache() {
    return $this->cache;
  }
  public function setCache($cache) {
    $this->cache = $cache;
  }
  public function getEntityLibrary() {
    return $this->entityLibrary;
  }
  public function setEntityLibrary($entityLibrary) {
    $this->entityLibrary = $entityLibrary;
  }
  public function getApplicationMode() {
    return $this->applicationMode;
  }
  public function setApplicationMode($applicationMode) {
    $this->applicationMode = $applicationMode;
  }
  public function getEntityManager() {
    return $this->entityManager;
  }
  public function setEntityManager($entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }
  /**   * Bootstrap Doctrine, setting the libraries and namespaces and creating * the entitymanager */
  public function bootstrap() {
    $this->registerClassLoader(); // Load cache 
    if ($this->getApplicationMode() == self::APP_MODE_DEVELOPMENT) {
      $this->cache = new ArrayCache;
    } else {
      $this->cache = new ApcCache;
    } /** @var $config Doctrine\ORM\Configuration */ $config = new Configuration;
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($this->cache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($this->getEntityLibrary());
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl($this->cache);
    $config->setProxyDir($this->getProxyLibrary());
    $config->setProxyNamespace($this->getProxyNamespace());
    if ($this->applicationMode == self::APP_MODE_DEVELOPMENT) {
      $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    } else {
      $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
    } $this->entityManager = EntityManager::create($this->getConnectionOptions(), $config);
  }
  /**   * Register the different classloaders for each type. */
  private function registerClassLoader() { // Autoloader for all the Doctrine library files 
//Doctrine was done by public_html/libraries/doctrine/vendor/autoload.php
//    $classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
//    $classLoader->register(); // Autoloader for all Entities 
//name of ComposerAutoloader is defined in /public_html/libraries/doctrine/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
    $modelLoader = ComposerAutoloaderInit825f56ea1383e6b7fef7ea99c51fea36::getLoader();
    $modelLoader->set("Entities\\",dirname(__FILE__)."/../../components/com_"
//not sure how to do the proxies yet, have to check this with production settings
//    $proxiesClassLoader = new ClassLoader('Proxies', $this->getProxyLibrary());
//    $proxiesClassLoader->register();
  }
}
?>
```

The Joomla model save function looks something like this (checking received JSON should be done in a controller or helper function):

```
  public function save() {
          //a textbox having the name 'json' or xhr post
      $link = JRequest::getVar('json',false,'post');
      if($link==false){
          return;
      }
      $link = json_decode($link);
      $newLink = new Link();
      $newLink->setId($link->id);
      $newLink->setName($link->name);
      foreach($link->categories as $category){
          $cat = new Category();
          $cat->setId($category->id);
          $cat->setName($category->name);
          $newLink->addCategorie($cat);
      }
      $this->em->persist($newLink);
      $this->em->flush();         
      return $link;
  }
```

I guess the code as is will break when using APP_MODE_PRODUCTION in /public_html/components/com_bugs/bugs.php